# How to extract the xml sent in a Http Post request through java?

Tags: java, xml, http, https

I am making a http post request in java and I need to see the xml which is sent in the request.
Is there a way to see that xml in java ? Please provide the method to print the request xml sent.

Sample code in java :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
       PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("***URL***");

       NameValuePair[] params = {
       new NameValuePair("dealerId", "***sampleDealerId***"), 
       new NameValuePair("queryId", "***sampleQueryId***") 
       };

       postMethod.setRequestBody(params);
       cl.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
       Credentials defaultCreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("***user***",    "***password***");
       cl.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultCreds);

       try { 
           try {
             cl.executeMethod(postMethod);
          }
           catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          BufferedReader br;

          try { 
            System.out.println(postMethod.getStatusCode()); 
            System.out.println(postMethod.getStatusText());
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(postMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream()),256);
                 String line;
                 char[] chars = new char[256];
                 while (br.read(chars) != -1) {
                    System.out.println(chars);
                    chars = new char[256];
                 }
          }
          catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
       finally {
        postMethod.releaseConnection();
       }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following logging parameters should enable the logging of the full wire contents (which should include the *XML* you're sending) and context. It's meant to work with the *Commons Logging* interface.

> -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
>   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true
>   -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http=DEBUG

The same level of debug for *log4j*:

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
>
> log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%c] %m%n
>
> log4j.logger.org.apache.http=DEBUG

[More info](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html)

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

The link above shows complete examples. It depends on which logging framework you're using. For example, if you're using *log4j*, a very common choice for logging, you would create a *log4j.properties* file with the specified *log4j* config parameters (the second block I specified above).

Once the log settings take effect, nothing explicitly should need to be printed in your code. Existing debug logging in the Apache HTTP code should log the responses/requests, among other stuff, assuming the right settings are in place.

Comment: Hey, can you please share more details how and where to set the logging parameters in the Commons Logging Interface ? Also what needs to be printed in the program to get the request xml ?